# zyBooks 1.24 LAB: Expression for calories burned during workout

Tags: python

I am writing a program accepting inputs;

- age (years)
- weight (pounds)
- heart rate (beats per minute)
- time (minutes)

respectively.
The output is the average calories burned for a person.

I get the correct answers but do not want age, hr or time to be floats.
Do I use a compound operator or what?
And how do I implement that into the code?

```
age_years = float(input())
weight_lbs = float(input())
heartrate_bpm = float(input())
time_min = float(input())


calories = ((age_years * 0.2757) + (weight_lbs * 0.03295) + (heartrate_bpm * 1.0781) - 75.4991) *     time_min / 8.368
#this is the formula for figuring average calories burned based on input by user

conv = str(age_years)
print('Age:', age_years , 'years old')

conv = str(weight_lbs)
print('Weight:' , weight_lbs , 'lbs')

conv = str(heartrate_bpm)
print('Heart Rate:' , heartrate_bpm , 'bpm')

print('Time:' , time_min , 'min')

print('Average calories burned during a workout: {:.2f} calories'.format(calories))
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it up into int:

```
print('Age:', int(age_years) , 'years old')
```

Comment: adding int( ) to the function worked thank you